# Chrome Web Extension, using buttons to open web page in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for the first time. It is relatively simple, all I want it to do is open up a web page in a new tab when a button is clicked. I am however not sure how to do this without javascript as I know chrome blocks inline `<script>` elements (or something like that). Below is my `popup.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>

.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4F5B62;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: "Roboto Mono";
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.button:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}

.button:after {
    content: "";
    background: #f1f1f1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 300%;
    padding-left: 350%;
    margin-left: -20px !important;
    margin-top: -120%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s
}

body{
  background-color: #263238;
}

head{
  background-color: #263238;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button type="button" class="button">Access chatter</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply use a separate popup.js file and the src attribute: `<script src="popup.js"></script>`

Comment: <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com.tr/', '_blank');">Access chatter</button> like this ?

Comment: Put your javascript in a separate file and include that file in the `popup.html` using  a `script` tag, like `<script src="popup.js"></script>`. You have examples in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

Comment: @tomclack Inline javascript is not allowed in Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### manifest.json

First you need to add the permission to use the `chrome.tabs` API in your `manifest.json`.

```
{
   ...
   "permissions": ["tabs"],
   ...
}
```

### popup.html

Then you can add an id to your button and the `popup.js` script at the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
   <button type="button" class="button" id="btn1">Access chatter</button>
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

### popup.js

And finally add the button action in your script.

#### Using vanilla JavaScript

```
var button = document.getElementById("btn1");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.google.com/"});
});
```

#### Using jQuery

If using jQuery be sure to add the corresponding script above the `popup.js` one.

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
   chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.google.com/"});
});
```

Comment: In order to use jQuery, you have to include the jQuery javascript file using another `script` tag above the one for `popup.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read about Getting Started with chrome extentions https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

And here you can see reference for creating new tab https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create